# Need convert function output to string from use as an arguement Python

Tags: python, string, function

Creating Hazel rule that triggers a script when a .mp4 file is dropped in.

Here is the script:

```
import os
from os import path

from vimeo import VimeoClient

a = "/Path/to/MyVimeoDirectory"

def myfile():
    for file in os.listdir("/Path/to/MyVimeoDirectory"):
        if file.endswith(".mp4"):
            return os.path.join(a, file)

vimeo = VimeoClient("blahblahvimeotoken")

vimeo.upload(myfile)
```

So basically vimeo.upload() requires a string argument. I've done a ton of research and saw some examples but I can't get them to work for me here. How do I get the resulting path of myfile() to put quotes around the output so I can use it as a string?  Thoughts?

Comment: Why do you think it isn't returning a string?

Comment: Are you getting any error output? If so please include those details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your final line, consider that you are passing `myfile` as an argument, and not `myfile()` -- and what the difference is.

A few suggestions: don't use `file` as the loop variable name since it ghosts the Python `file` builtin and at the very least makes it confusing to read quickly; Are you sure the loop does what you want? It appears to return just the first appearing .mp4 file from the list of files as `os.listdir` orders them. `myfile` *does not* return *all* of the .mp4 files.

Comment: I can't believe it... Feel like such an idiot. It was the myfile vs myfile() .... Made the change and done. Worked perfectly. Thanks for the help.